# All files unattached in Media Library

Tags: uploads, media, paths

After moving to new host all files unattached in Media Library, need a way to re-attach them.

Thanks

Comment: Have you flushed your permalinks after migration?

Comment: How, specifically, did you perform the migration?

Comment: Copied all files to new host and export import DB.

OLD Host Path
/home/awidea/public_html/muslimblog.co.in

New Host Path
/home1/awideaco/public_html/muslimblog